# Topology in which there is a subbase smaller than any base.

Tags: general-topology

Does a topoogy $\tau$ exist such that there is a subbase of $\tau$ which has smaller cardinality than any base? I am specially interested in the case where the underlying set is finite.

Thank you kindly,

Regards.

Comment: I bet you can construct one on a set with three points.

Comment: OK, now how about an example in which every base is infinite?

Comment: @Pete the basis generated by a subbasis has the same cardinality as the subbasis when it is infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another example, let $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,2,3\}$, and consider the discrete topology on the 6-element set $A \times B$.  (Try drawing it as a $2 \times 3$ grid.)  Any base has size at least 6 since it must contain all the singletons.  But you can get a subbase of size 5 by considering the "row and column" sets
$$\{1\} \times B, \quad \{2\} \times B, \quad A \times \{1\}, \quad A \times \{2\}, \quad A \times \{3\}.$$
Of course you can continue this construction to get a set where every base has size $n^2$ but there is a subbase of size $2n$.

Answer (score 3):

$\{x,y,z\}$ is the set, $\{\{\},\{x,y\},\{y,z\},\{y\},\{x,y,z\}\}$ has a subbasis with two elements and a basis has at least three elements.